# Forcing `Interactive mode` in the VSCode Python debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

If I run a Python program under the debugger in VSCode, and the program
has the line `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, I see the following
message in the Python Debug Console (under the `TERMINAL` tab):

```
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
```

This is desired, as now I don't have to type `plt.show()` after every
`plt.plot()` when I'm exploring data in the REPL under the
`DEBUG CONSOLE` tab.

The problem is, not every program has that `import` line, and so I'm
forced to manually do so in the debug REPL, and follow each `plt.plot()`
with a `plt.show()`.

My question: Is there a way to force this 'interactive mode',
perhaps through the `launch.json` file? I've looked at the docs for `launch.json`
but don't see anything applicable.

I'm using VSCode 1.63.2 on Windows 10 Version 20H2.